# Getting users list from active directory using Slim Framework

Tags: php, ldap

I'm trying to get a list with the name and email from our Active Directory. I got it, but when I put the code into a Slim function for response a `json` which containing the name and email values I get this:

> Undefined index: mail

If I put the same code out of Slim it runs fine. Any idea why?

This is how I get the Active Directory info:

```
$sr=ldap_search($ADconn, "OU=company,DC=name", "cn=*");  
$info = ldap_get_entries($ADconn, $sr);
echo $info["count"]." resultats trobats: <br>";

 for ($i=0; $i<$info["count"]; $i++) {
        $results[] = array(
            'nom' => $info[$i]["cn"] [0],
            'correu' => $info[$i]["mail"][0]
        );
    }
```

Out of Slim works , but inside it's not.

Comment: Can you show the Slim Route you make? This works so we need to see what does not. My assumption you are not passing in $ADconn.

Comment: I don't need it but thanks anyway

Comment: Are you sure the `mail` attribute is defined for every user account? If it doesn't have a value then LDAP wont return it. You could change it to `'correu' => isset($info[$i]["mail"]) ? $info[$i]["mail"][0] : '';`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I'm out of this project this now. Thanks anyway